# get text via re in python

Tags: python, regex

Please help me get the values from string between characters using regular expression.

For example, I have the string : "-hlocalhost-uuser-ppassword" and from this I must get the strings variables "localhost", "user", "password".

Thanks

Comment: just use `str.split('-')[1:]`(you dont want the stuff before the first dash), no need for regex. this will return a list

Comment: Are you parsing command-line arguments? If so, consider using https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html

Comment: thank you all for the help, but i need to user exactly re

Comment: Then show what you have tried using exactly re?  and you probably need to bound the problem better... will it also be -h<host>-u<user>-p<password> or could the order vary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
a = "-hlocalhost-uuser-ppassword"
localhost, user, password = [x[1:] for x in a.split("-")[1:]]
```

Edit :
If you want to use `re` then the following will work

```
import re
a = "-hlocalhost-uuser-ppassword"
b = re.split("(-h)|(-u)|(-p)", a)[1:]
a = [x for x in b if x is not None]
b = dict(zip(a[0::2], a[1::2]))
print b
```

prints `{'-u': 'user', '-h': 'localhost', '-p': 'password'}`

Not very clean, but works well even if you skip some parameters or change the order of parameters. If someone posts a better method, it will be a good learning opportunity.

Comment: Thank you for the help. But in my case need exactry re

Comment: Sorry! Didn't see that. Let me see if I can come up with something.

Comment: @JustMe: I have edited my answer. Is this the answer you are looking for ?